Tab-completion in Minibuffer underlines and uses only current input, even if partial completion is shown
I've installed emacs 30.0.60 on Android.
Tab-completion in the minibuffer for file names and for commands does not work as I am used to it with emacs -Q.
Assume, there exists a file name ~/notes.org and I call find-file with ~/ as default-directory.
Emacs offers me the initial input ~/. When I input not and then hit the TAB key, Emacs shows the completion ~/notes.org but underlines the substring not. If I hit RET I only get a file buffer for the new file ~/not instead of that one for ~/notes.org.
What does cause this behavior and how can I customize Emacs such that it uses the full completion ~/notes.org as file name for find-file?

Is this specific to the Android version?  If you compile the same version on your desktop PC, do you get the same behaviour under emacs -Q from both?

I installed 30.0.50 from F-Droid and it behaves the same way.
According to the documentation, it is an intentional change.
The completions buffer says,

Type M-RET on a completion to select it.

The NEWS.30 file expands on this,

*** Selected completion candidates are deselected on typing.
When you type at the minibuffer prompt, the current completion
candidate will be un-highlighted, and point in the "Completions" window
will be moved off that candidate.  'minibuffer-choose-completion'
('M-RET') will still choose a previously-selected completion
candidate, but the new command 'minibuffer-choose-completion-or-exit'
(bound to 'RET' by 'minibuffer-visible-completions') will exit with
the minibuffer contents instead.  This deselection behavior can be
controlled with the new user option 'completion-auto-deselect', which
is t by default.

Reading that, I expect desktop builds to behave the same way. I didn't make time to test it properly as I couldn't type M-<up>, and didn't try to rebind (minibuffer-previous-completion) to another key. However, I recommend you change completion-auto-deselect to nil to see if that restores the version 29 behaviour that you like.
Footnotes:

Main commit for this feature: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/3c093148958d56e0ed8e12a8e00ced1ef052259a
If you have a touch screen, tap the completion to open the file
GUI Emacs on my phone seems clumsy without a physical keyboard attached. The termux package (version 29.4) is simpler for me to use with an on-screen keyboard.


Thanks for the effort. I tried this option already beforehand. Pityingly it does not resolve the problem completely. Especially, if I type not for the file notes.org and hit the TAB-key the file is completed to notes.org, but if I hit RET a new buffer with file name not is opened instead of the buffer for the existing file notes.org.

Somehow it has nothing to do with the *Completions* buffer. It is already something within completion-at-point, when it partially completes the minibuffer input.

What happens when you hit M-RET? As it is a pre-release build, I suggest posting a bug report: completion-auto-deselect doesn't appear to be working as documented for you. (By the way, is there an on-screen keyboard app or plugin that works well with this new build? Or have you attached a physical keyboard? )

After your hint about the soft-keyboard, I installed "Unexpected Keyboard" (FDroid-Version) along with "Hacker's Keyboard" (Android-Version). Interestingly, the problem occurs with "Hacker's Keyboard" but NOT with "Unexpected Keyboard". (I didn't expect this!)
